# power bi count multiple values in column

Tags: excel, powerbi

I am working with excel online and power bi, I have a table with the following columns:

```
| incident A |  March   |  Lifting      
| incident B |  April   |  Lifting  
| incident C |  March   |  Lifting; Slips Trips
| incident d |  March   |  Lifting; Slips Trips
```

I am trying to get this outcome:

```
March 3 lifting 
      2 Slips Trips

April 1 lifting
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you want to get this in powerBI or in excel?

Comment: In powerBI please, the end result should be present it in  a table and chart in powerBI , thank you so much